# Xamarin Forms ios displaying "default" instead of Hamburger Icon

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

Hi there I'm creating a Xamarin Forms application with Prism and everything is running smoothly bar one small UI issue. The ios version is displaying the following :

[image]

The Hamburger menu is not showing and in its place is a piece of text labeled "default".The issue is only occurring in the ios version. I researched the issue and some mentioned that you must wrap it in a navigation page. However on my app startup I wrap the page in a navigation page using the prism navigation service:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationService.navigateAsync("WelcomePage/NavPage/TBHomePage");
}
```

If anyone has experienced this before it would be a create help
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: How are you setting the icon property? Is it in your Resources folder?

Comment: I have not manually set it on either platform. I assumed it would use the out of the box icon as Android does?

Comment: iOS doesn't have that icon natively.

Comment: So for forms i have to manually set the icon for it in the platform specific project? ok gotcha the examples I have been looking at all have the icons and do not mention any platform specific work involved. Thanks for the tip @valdetero

Comment: You have to specify that it has an icon on the Forms project and then add the resource to the platform project. I added an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a hamburger icon in its system icons. You will have to manually add it. Here's a github project where I added a menu icon to a Xamarin.Forms project.

https://github.com/valdetero/SevenDays/blob/master/SevenDays.UI/SevenDays.UI/Views/MenuPage.cs#L17

```cs
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    public MenuPage()
    {
        Icon = PlatformImage.Resolver("menu.png");
        Title = "menu"; // The Title property must be set.
```

Then make sure you have the required resolutions (1x, @2x, @3x) in your `Resources` folder.

https://github.com/valdetero/SevenDays/tree/master/SevenDays.UI/SevenDays.UI.iOS/Resources

`PlatformImage.Resolver` only had formatted the path per platform:

```cs
public static string Resolver(string image)
{
    return string.Format(Device.OnPlatform("{0}", "{0}", "Assets/{0}"), image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your share and your recomend solved my problem.